# Why does HTML TextArea have its own HTML tag?

Tags: html

```
<input id='input1' type='text'></input>
<input id='input2' type='button'></input>
<input id='input3' type='checkbox'><input>
<textarea id='myTextArea'></textarea>
```

In HTML markup, most places where the user can interact with the page are denoted with the `<input>` tag.  Why is it that textarea has its own tag, `<textarea>` as opposed so, say, `<input type='textarea'>`

Comment: Lots of good answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637326/why-isnt-textarea-an-inputtype-textarea

Comment: This should be reopened.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because `<textarea>` has the `rows` and `cols` attributes that are specific to it. If it were a type of `<input>`, these attributes would have to be part of the `<input>` tag even though they serve no purpose for the other types.

Comment: Strangely, though, `<input type="checkbox">` and `<input type="radio">` have a `checked` attribute not used by any other input type. Similarly, `<input type="image">` shares attributes with the `<img>` tag. Additionally, `<input type="button">` shares functionality with the `<button>` tag.

Comment: @greyfade: Let he whose incremental designs are completely consistent cast the first stone...

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt where can I buy that t-shirt? :)

Answer (score 26):

Okay, @maple_shaft's answer got me curious, so after about 20 minutes of Googling...

From one of the original [HTML drafts](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-html-spec-00):

> NOTE: In the initial design for forms, multi-line text fields were
> supported by the Input element with TYPE=TEXT. Unfortunately, this
> causes problems for fields with long text values. SGML's default
> (Reference Quantity Set) limits the length of attribute literals to
> only 240 characters. The HTML 2.0 SGML declaration increases the limit
> to 1024 characters.

So no, it did **not** have to do with `rows` and `cols` being unique to textarea, like the accepted answer claims.

Comment: The currently accepted answer is decidedly not correct.  The stackoverflow question linked to in grahamparks comment also has accurate answers (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637326/why-isnt-textarea-an-inputtype-textarea).

Comment: @Izkata Thanks for finding and posting this!  Most people wouldn't have cared enough to revive an old question with new information.

Comment: @maple_shaft I've often wondered the same thing, though, but didn't really have an idea where to start searching.  Got the idea from your answer  (Plus this one isn't that old, I've posted new stuff to SciFi.SE for Star Trek after a year or more (^_~) )

Answer (score 7):

To understand why the `textarea` is a unique tag compared to the other input fields you would have needed to be in the original message chains between Conolly and Berners-Lee in the years leading up to the release of the HTML 2.0 standard that came out in 1995.  Why it is not a standard `input` tag like everything else may have been because of a technical difficulty at the time or some general compromise that they had agreed upon.

For the original HTML 2.0 specification on HTML Forms see here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1866#section-8

At one point someone had found the original AOL message boards and posted them publicly where they were going back and forth discussing the various prototypes that led up to HTML as we know it today.  It was intensely interesting but I can't seem to find it anymore.

Comment: Hopefully someone can find it.

Comment: @Chad - I didn't find the messages, but see my just-posted answer